# ANTLR - Embedding Java code, evaluate before or after?

Tags: java, dynamic, parsing, antlr, grammar

I'm writing a simple scripting language on top of Java/JVM, where you can also embed Java code using the `{}` brackets. The problem is, how do I parse this in the grammar? I have two options:

1. Allow everything to be in it, such as: `[a-z|a-Z|0-9|_|$]`, and go on
2. Get an extra java grammar and use that grammar to parse that small code (is it actually possible and efficient?)

Since option 2] is basically a double-check since when evaluating java code it's also being checked. Now my last question is -- is way that can dynamically execute java code also with objects which have been created at runtime?

Thanks,

William van Doorn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1] Allow everything to be in it, such as: [a-z|a-Z|0-9|_|$], and go on

You can't just do that: you'll have to account for opening and closing brackets.

> 2] Get an extra java grammar and use that grammar to parse that small code (is it actually possible and efficient?)

Yes that's possible. But I suggest you first get something working, and then worry about efficiency (is that really an issue here?).

> ... is way that can dynamically execute java code also with objects which have been created at runtime?

Yes, since Java 6, there's a way to compile source files dynamically. See the [JavaCompiler](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) API.

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark this as answer, but, it looks like the JavaCompiler API only accepts file instances instead of plain lines?

Comment: @wvd: yes, you'll have to write your Java source (as String(s)) to a file first.

Answer (score 0):

I propose enclose your Java code inside characters like '`' which are not used in Java code and barely present in literals.

JavaCode:  '`' ( EscapeSequence | ~('\\'|'`') )* '`'
    ;

Use java.g provided by antlr examples to get definition of EscapeSequence ,...

The only catch is that you need to ask programmers to use code of this character ('`') if it is required to be as an literal.